# How to get FB users with GraphAPI

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-object

We need to be able to retrieve public_profile for users by user_name on FB.
Unfortunately, I can't find the way to retrieve this data from FB.
Do you know if there any way to do it?
Any ideas / solutions /leads are more then welcome.

Thanks in advance!

We tried Graph API explorer to find the available API, but had no luck so far.

Comment: No, there is not. You only get user data, after the user logged in to your app and granted it permission.